# What is the type of system, if I have an opened container with hot water inside, but no heat input to the system?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility, adiabatic

I have a school project, where I am trying to generate electricity using TEG modules that are attached to an aluminium container that contains hot water. The container is opened and there is no heat input to the system. So I am wondering what is the type of the thermodynamical process occuring inside of the system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are not adding heat, what keeps the water boiling?

Answer (score 0):

A system that can *potentially* exchange mass with its surroundings is by definition an open system. This applies regardless of whether or not there is an actual exchange of mass or an exchange of energy in the form of heat and/or work. So your open container of water is an open system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. What I mean is that I have poured boiling water inside of the container, but the water inside is not boiling. The thing that I am asking about is what is the type of the process occuring; is it adiabatic or isobaric or something else? Thank you for your response, and I am sorry for not choosing the right words.